# PHP Curl on login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: php, curl, powerbi

I am trying to create an application that uses CURL to authenticate in Microsoft form.

My goal is for our internal environment to log in to PowerBI without the credentials being requested to the user, for this I wrote the following code:

```
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br';
    $headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
    $headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length:1813';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $headers[] = 'Host:login.microsoftonline.com';
    $headers[] = 'Origin:https://login.microsoftonline.com';
    $headers[] = 'Referer:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=871c010f-5e61-4fb1-83ac-98610a7e9110&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3deTdt2Db6cxkyjwUrf6qBsf0o4RmcyEarBafcxh-TWNPVM1d8qBEPlqj9ndHtjI7bTriFjKxM3gcNoNTODFeK_liRiY6Gjw7SnAuHJ_je0d2PescB5_Q3yqkMfGZuHPwdZgN1Ow&nonce=636270125908033382.ODU3NTU1NjAtN2VkZC00OTgzLWE4MzUtNDU4MGFmY2EwYjU3NDcxNjE0MDQtNTRmYy00MjdiLThlZDEtZDIwOWNiODM3MzY5&site_id=500453&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fapp.powerbi.com%2f%3fnoSignUpCheck%3d1&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fapp.powerbi.com%2f%3fnoSignUpCheck%3d1&resource=https%3a%2f%2fanalysis.windows.net%2fpowerbi%2fapi&nux=1&msafed=0';
    $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1';
    $headers[] = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36';
    $headers[] = 'Cookie: ' . $web["cookies"];


    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login';
    $poststring = "ALL FORM FIELDS";
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $poststring);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Note: $web["cookies"] comes from a previous request to get all necessary cookies

When I do an analysis of what is being sent when I enter the site and what is being sent by CURL everything is exactly the same.

The problem is that the CURL is trying to connect for a long time and when it finishes the return comes empty

Any help ?

Comment: you will probably find automation like this is a breach of terms

Comment: `comes up empty` - i refuse to believe that. maybe STDOUT comes up empty, sure, but you forget to check php's STDERR, there definitely should be something there, which should explain why STDOUT is empty. check php's error log

Comment: also, you send `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`, but your code does not handle the situation in which the server actually CHOOSE to use 1 of those encodings. luckily for you, curl usually has built-in support for gzip and deflate, which you can enable with CURLOPT_ENCODING

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is in your `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Not sure about `ALL FORM FIELDS`, but `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts either a URL-encoded string of parameters (`para1=val1&para2=val2&...`), or a JSON-encoded array (`json_encode(array("firstname"  => "John"))`).

Comment: also, you hardcode `Content-Length:1813`, but you actually should let curl send that header automatically, less chance of you screwing it up and sending the wrong value

Comment: @ObsidianAge form fields are ok like login=USER&passwd= (and a lot of fields).

Comment: @hanshenrik i check the STDERR, create a file to check it and nothing, what you suggest about Content-Lenght, the form size ?

Comment: Just for note, i'm sending the same data on headers and form that the page expect.